# Python - Return Listbox selection as a list

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have come across several solutions to problems more complicated than the one I have, so I apologize if this is a repeat but I can't seem to adapt other solutions to my needs in this instance.

I need show a populated list box and use multiple selection method to return the selection as a list that I can split up and manipulate later.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *

def onselect(evt):
    w = evt.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    selection = [w.get(int(i)) for i in w.curselection()]
    return selection

master = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(master,selectmode=MULTIPLE)

listbox.pack()

for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

mainloop()
```

**How do I correctly store the selection variable as a list?**

Comment: What is wrong with your code so far

Comment: Perhaps I am not accessing the selection list right?
I can't figure out how to access it, I need to create directories with the values of the list.

Comment: Are you saying onselect isn't getting called?

Comment: I believe it is,  if i add "print selection" to onselect it will print a line showing the selection every time it changes. 
I need to access it outside the function to automatically create directories that have the names that equal the values of the selection.

Comment: Since you don't seem to be using any kind of class structure anyway, just use a global variable

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm very new to this and learning as I go. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning this topic myself. If I understand correctly, you want to store and use this list for future use. I think defining the listbox as a class, and storing the list as a class attribute is the way to go.

The following borrows from Programming Python, 4th ed, Ch. 9. The list in the future could be accessed as myList.selections as needed.

```
from tkinter import *


class myList(Frame):
    def __init__(self, options, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.makeWidgets(options)
        self.selections = []

    def onselect(self, event):
        selections = self.listbox.curselection()
        selections = [int(x) for x in selections]
        self.selections = [options[x] for x in selections]
        print(self.selections)

    def makeWidgets(self, options):
        listbox = Listbox(self, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
        listbox.pack()
        for item in options:
            listbox.insert(END, item)
        listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.onselect)
        self.listbox = listbox


if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    myList(options).mainloop()
```

Comment: It dynamically updates the selection in the interactive window, so that definitely works. Thank you
How do I access the list though?
Say I need to name a folder the same value as the nth index?

Comment: @N_8_ I tried to code a quick example but failed. Short, poor answer is I think it depends on whether the list needs to be accessed while the interface loop is running, or after its termination. If the former, and you packed an instance of myList (e.g. "Bob") into a larger frame, then `folder name = Bob.selections[n]` should work. If not, "Bob" would have to pass on the info before it "dies", and I'm still learning how that works :) Maybe in a couple weeks I could give a better answer.